# Check existing mounts against /etc/fstab and report missing mounts?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

I've got an environment that I didn't build that was handed off to me and it's scheduled for the first round of updates.  Unfortunately the client believes that some mount points may have been added by non-sysadmins on some servers and wants us to be able to add the mount points into /etc/fstab for anything that is currently missing.

Their current plan is to have us just collect mount information on the current running servers and assist with any missing mounts after reboot. That's fine, but I'd like to ensure those mounts ARE in /etc/fstab prior to rebooting if possible.

I'm hoping to get a script or command to audit /proc/mount, check the existing mounts against /etc/fstab, and report any mounts that are live but missing in /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 0):

Simple script - it will miss the mark if people mess with the mounts in the fstab as it is only looking at the mount points.  I did not look at the mount source as that would require a more involved script and I can not put time into that at this time.

```
### Shows your current mounted points.
mount | sed '/^#/d' | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d" " -f3 | sort > cur_mounts.txt

### Shows /etc/fstab mounted points
cat /etc/fstab | sed '/^#/d' | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d" " -f2 | sort > fstab_mounts.txt

### Displays differences between the file mount points (if a mount point has been changed since bootup - it will not catch it (say umount and mount-ing a different reference).
diff cur_mounts.txt fstab_mounts.txt
```